# How do you keep Android from resizing the logo of the actionbar?

Tags: android, resize, android-actionbar, manifest

I have created a logo for my application, so I am not using an icon. I designed the logo fitting nicely in the actionbar but I can't figure out how to keep Android from resizing my logo.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you use if you don't use an icon ? Do you draw each pixel through code ?

Answer (score 1):

Provide different images for each density: mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi.

Comment: I did, but android automaticly makes it "fit" with a border, I want the logo to fully fit on the screen as intended

Comment: You might want to post a screenshot and the code you are using to set the logo.